# Не переключается уровень языка в IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea

В разделе Moduls переключаю уровень языка на 7.0, но при компиляции все равно используется 1.5.

В чем проблема может быть?

Comment: Ctrl + Alt + Shift + S в разделе Project, смотрите какая версия SDK стоит для всех модулей проекта.

Comment: ну вот вроде стоит который надо, но все равно не получается

Answer (score 2):

Если в проекте используется maven то в нем тоже надо поменять примерно так:

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
```

Comment: не помог ваш совет:(

Comment: @Pavel а какая версия Идеи? Есть где нибудь пример проекта чтобы проверить у себя?